# Browsers crash when using URL.createObjectURL

Tags: android, html

Using android, browsers (FF, Chrome, ...) crash when i use this instruction :

```
img.src = blob;
```

Any idea ?

the complete source :

```
$("#file-input").on("change", function (e) {
    if (window.URL) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.onload = function (e) {
            img.width = 100;
            document.getElementById("preview").appendChild(img);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
            parent.window.$.mobile.loading("show");
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                startUploading();
            }, 2500);
        };
        var blob = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        img.src = blob;
    }
    else {
        // fallback to FileReader for FF3.6
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = ['<img src="', e.target.result, '" width="100" />'].join('');
                parent.window.$.mobile.loading("show");
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    startUploading();
                }, 2500);
            };
        })(f);
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
});
```

thanks in advance.